# COM object and returned QVariant casting issue

Tags: c++, qt, casting, com

I'm trying to use the COM object and I'm having trouble casting a returned function value. I am using Qt 5.7.0 and I got .h and .cpp file for COM object with dumpcpp tool.

```
class SCAPILIB_EXPORT IAttrList : public QAxObject
{
public:
    IAttrList(IDispatch *subobject = 0, QAxObject *parent = 0)
    : QAxObject((IUnknown*)subobject, parent)
    {
        internalRelease();
    }

    /*
    Method AddItem

    method AddItem

    */
    inline void AddItem(Attr Attribute, const QVariant& value);

    /*
    Method FindItemIndex

    method FindItemIndex

    */
    inline int FindItemIndex(int startIndex, SCAPILib::Attr Attribute);

    /*
    Method GetCount

    method GetCount

    */
    inline int GetCount();

    /*
    Method GetIndex

    method GetIndex

    */
    inline QVariant GetIndex(int index, Attr& pAttribute);

    /*
    Method GetItem

    method GetItem

    */
    inline QVariant GetItem(Attr Attribute);

    /*
    Method OutputToString

    method OutputToString

    */
    inline QString OutputToString();

    /*
    Method RestoreFromBlob

    method RestoreFromBlob

    */
    inline void RestoreFromBlob(QVariant blob);

    /*
    Method SaveToBlob

    method SaveToBlob

    */
    inline void SaveToBlob(QVariant& pBlob);

    /*
    Method SetIndex

    method SetIndex

    */
    inline void SetIndex(int index, SCAPILib::Attr Attribute, const QVariant& value);

// meta object functions
    static const QMetaObject staticMetaObject;
    virtual const QMetaObject *metaObject() const { return &staticMetaObject; }
    virtual void *qt_metacast(const char *);
};
```

The function GetItem always returned a QVariant, usually the QVariant contain a QString, QInt or QBool, but with a determinate attribute the returned value will be a pointer to the base class (`IAttrList *`).

```
inline QVariant IAttrList::GetItem(Attr Attribute)
{
    QVariant qax_result;
    void *_a[] = {(void*)&qax_result, (void*)&Attribute};
    qt_metacall(QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod, 12, _a);
    return qax_result;
}
```

I can use the function of the COM object just fine, except when it will be return a indicated class pointer. In this case de QVariant returned type is `IUnknown *` and I not able to cast this to `IAttrLits *`.

I'm tried with:

```
IAttrList * Attr = AttrList.GetItem(Some_Attribute).Value<IAttrList *>();
```

But compiler returned error: static assertion failed: qobject_cast requires the type to have a Q_OBJECT macro

Which I understand is normal because, according to Qt documentation, classes derived from QAxObject can not contain the Q_OBJECT macro.

I have also tried with:

```
IAttrList * attr = static_cast<IAttrList *>(AttrList.GetItem(Some_attribute).data());
```

and

```
IAttrList * attr = static_cast<IAttrList *>(AttrList.GetItem(Some_attribute).value<void *>();
```

It compiles but the AttrList pointer does not seem to be valid because I get a segmentation fault when trying to use it.

What might the problem be?

Comment: you should use QueryInterface on the IUnkown asking for the interface you desire.  You shouldn't make assumptions in COM that the IUnkown is directly castable to the type you desire.

Comment: Thanks for answer,

I dont sure about the use of queryinterface. Do you referer to somethink like this?

QVariant var = AttrList.GetItem (some_attribute);

AttrList.queryInterface (some_UUID, (void **) var);

How do I get the UUID to class IAttrList?. Thanks again.

Comment: unfortunately I do not have or use Qt... so I cannot answer specifics for the library.  UUID is a number, if you have done a typelib import there will often be a constant for that.  the queryInterface should be done on the IUnkown object that you received as a return value.  This asks for a pointer resolved to the class that interface.  Otherwise it will return an error when the interface is not support.  Why you should do this is because there is no guarantee that for any interface you can directly cast to another interface. The provider for the interface could be a child of the class.

Comment: The class I have obtained with the tool dumpcpp and have defined any UUID. I have assigned one with the SetControl method and I called the QueryInterface procedure:
 
`HRESULT Hr = AttrList.QueryIntrface (IID_AttrList, (void **) & var);`

But this always returns, `0x80004001 **E_NOTIMPL**`

It is frustrating that something that in .Net is achieved with a simple assignment may be giving me so many headaches.

Thanks once again.

Comment: Not implemented means it does have this interface. This likely means what you think is a AttrList is not.  Actually when I re-read your description I see you get a "QVariant" which is likely build similar to a COM Variant.  So you likely have to cast to QVariant and then attempt to get the value from it.  Looking at the QVariant online doc doesn't show an ArrayList type... Perhaps you need QList?  there is a type() that will tell you what the variant is holding.

Answer (score 0):

1: Try this :

```
IAttrList Attr(AttrList.GetItem(Some_Attribute));
```

2: If you can extract an `IUnknown*` or `IDispatch*` from the `AttrList.GetItem(Some_Attribute)` use it as this :

```
IAttrList Attr((Extracted IUnknown* or IDispatch*));
```

Since the constructor `IAttrList` is like `IAttrList(IDispatch *subobject = 0, QAxObject *parent = 0)
    : QAxObject((IUnknown*)subobject, parent)`

I hope this would help you, I had a similar problem using Qt and the first code helped me solve it.